# How to use default values for empty parameters in FastAPI

Tags: python, validation, pytest, fastapi

I've got a task on the project to update some packages versions due to security reasons. I updated `FastAPI` from 0.63.0 to 0.95.2. But one test started to fail.

This test makes a API request in the following format:
`https://.../api/v2/list/?limit=&offset=12&...`.

And I'm getting the following response:

```
Status code: 422 Unprocessable Entity
JSON: {'detail': [{'loc': ['query', 'limit'], 'msg': 'value is not a valid integer', 'type': 'type_error.integer'}]}
```

The error occurs because of empty parameter `limit=`.

There is a view:

```py
async def get_list(
        ...
        limit: int = Query(10, lt=max_int_value),
        ...
) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
    ...
```

**So the question is:** Is there a way to make it use default value (10) instead of raising 422 in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, if you want to use an `Optional` query param, then you need to import `from typing import Optional` and use it. This allows the param to not be given at all in which case, it will set it to use the default value.

Here's an sample of how you can modify your get_list function to achieve this:

```py
from typing import Optional, List, Dict, Any
from fastapi import Query

async def get_list(
        ...
        limit: Optional[int] = Query(
           default=10, 
           lt=max_int_value,
           title="Limit",
           description="Limit Query Param for blah blah",
        ),
        ...
) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
```

If this is still causing issues, then most prolly, your FastAPI version sets the value for `limit` as `None` as this is one of the consequences of using `Optional`. In this case, just use a precheck in the API function like:

```py
async def get_list(
        ...
        limit: Optional[int] = Query(
           default=10, 
           lt=max_int_value,
           title="Limit",
           description="Limit Query Param for blah blah",
        ),
        ...
) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
     # Precheck
     limit: int = limit or 10
     ....
```

Hope this clarifies your question.